# Adding a back button to MessagingViewController Page

Tags: ios, navigation, swift2

My app involves creating a feed. I have a navigation bar leading into the feed, and tab bar at the bottom of the feed leading to a messaging page (NavigationController -> FeedViewController -> MessagingViewController). I want a back button option in the messaging page to lead back to the feed. However, I am unsure how to do this. I added in a Navigation Bar to my Messaging View Controller with a back button. However, the navigation bar is not even visible. Any advice on how to do this?

[Storyboard Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZwjJ.png)

This is a picture of our storyboard. Right now we got rid of the code that added the back button because it did not seem to work correctly. We hid the tabBarController in our ChatChat screen.

Comment: Add some code that you are using.

Comment: I added my storyboard! We do not have much in code right now @NiravDoctorwala